# Commands Not Found when Passed through SSH

Tags: shell-script, ssh, command-line

**System:**

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo), 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64

**GOAL:**

Collect configurations for data from multiple servers to validate they are the same.

**What Works:**

```
ssh $SERVERNAME 'yum list installed | grep -E "krb|java|libkadm|realmd|oddjob|sssd|adcli"' >> $FILENAME
```

**What Doesn't Work:**

```
ssh $SERVERNAME 'adcli info domain.name' >> $FILENAME
ssh $SERVERNAME 'realm list' >> $FILENAME
```

**Error Received:**

bash: adcli: command not found

bash: realm: command not found

**Full Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`

SERVERLIST=(
#"server1.com"
"server2.com"
"server3.com"
#"server4.com"
"server5.com"
)

for SERVERNAME in ${SERVERLIST[*]}
do
        FILENAME=${SERVERNAME}-config.${DATE}
        ssh $SERVERNAME 'yum list installed | grep -E "krb|java|libkadm|realmd|oddjob|sssd|adcli"' >> $FILENAME
        ssh $SERVERNAME 'adcli info domain.name' >> $FILENAME
        ssh $SERVERNAME 'realm list' >> $FILENAME
        ssh $SERVERNAME 'cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf' >> $FILENAME
done
```

Comment: Those errors would indicate that the `adcli` and `realm` commands are not in the `$PATH` of the user you are connecting as.  You should probably be using absolute paths for the locations of those programs, or you could add whatever directory they are in to your user's `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Just to clarify, those commands are in the user I connected as. When I SSH and run `echo $PATH` I have the same directories, but when I only pass a command through SSH, it doesn't work.
You are correct that not all directories are loaded when passing the command through ssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GracefulRestart is almost certainly correct.

No verify, compare the output of $PATH between on-server exec and ssh to server exec:

`[server2.com]# echo $PATH
 [jumpbox]# ssh server2.com 'echo $PATH'`

If the path to 'adcli' & 'realm' are missing on the ssh $PATH env variable, then the simplest way to fix is to simply use the full path.